# ember link-to a subroute inside dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

in my router i have

```
 this.route('users', { path: '/users' }, function(){
 this.route('show', { path: '/:user_id' }, function(){
    this.route('history',{ path: '/history' });
 });});
```

in my template i want to link to the users/1/history url
but `{{#link-to "users.show.history" user}}History{{/link-to}}`
is not working.
So what is the correct way to write this link to?

Comment: What is not working? Do you have any errors (browser console or computer terminal) that would help discover the problem?

Comment: What you had already written in the question is the correct way to achieve what you want indeed. Check out the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a5fcf0e56e9412402ea0b26aa4ac880e?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C&route=%2Fusers%2F3%2Fhistory). We should help better if you give information about what is not working, any particular error message you get. But regarding your question; the correct way declaring a `link-to` to a subroute inside a dynamic segment is working as expected as you can see in the twiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works right now, it turns out that it has something to do with my model is not setting up correctly